# aggregation with respect to one field except one value of that field

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am writing a query to do aggregation with respect to one field, however, I want to exclude this aggregation for one value of that field

```
let coAuthorCutThreshold =100

network.aggregate([
  { $group: { _id: '$title', title :{$ne: "class notes"}, count: { $sum: 1 } }} ,
  { $match: { count: { $gt: coAuthorCutThreshold } } },
  { $sort: { count: -1 } }
]).forEach(function (obj) {
  cutTitles.push(obj._id)
});
```

I want to do aggregation with respect to title but do to not want to do aggregation where the title is "class notes". I tried many command but did not work

I want to include all those values in cutTitles except where title is "class notes"

Comment: Add a match stage before the group stage, and define it to filter out documents with title: "class notes"

Comment: if I will use match with "class notes" only, then it will give me only for "class notes", but there are many other titles except that that I want too. But not those titles that occur more than 100 times

Comment: "_define it to filter out documents with the title_" is different than "_filter it by listing out all of the titles that you do want_".  Check out `$ne`

Comment: Sorry, I figured {title: {$ne: "class notes"}} was obvious since it's present in the question's group stage. The MongoDB manual has [a page](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) describing its use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match in order to filter out the documents you don't want to group before the group stage.

```
let coAuthorCutThreshold = 100

network.aggregate([
  { $match: { title: { $ne: "class notes" }}},
  { $group: { _id: '$title', count: { $sum: 1 }}},
  { $match: { count: { $gt: coAuthorCutThreshold }}},
  { $sort: { count: -1 }}
]).forEach(function (obj) {
  cutTitles.push(obj._id)
});
```

Comment: Thanks! this is new to me that I can use $match twice in aggregation. Yes, it worked!

Comment: You're welcome. An aggregation pipeline may have up to 1000 stages. There exist limits on which stages may occur in various sequences, but generally you can mix them as you please.